# Android creating listview with multiple countdown timer not working

Tags: java, android, listview, timer, countdown

i am new to android. Currently i am facing problem when trying to create countdown timer in every items in my listview in a listfragment class. The timer is not counting down and it is stucked there. Can anyone help me to look for my problem?

This is my listview class.

```
public class OneFragment extends ListFragment {

View rootView;
TextView scheduleId;
ListAdapter listadapter;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scheduleList = controller.getAllSchedules();
    if (scheduleList.size()!=0){
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                scheduleId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleId);
                String getId = scheduleId.toString();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getId, duration);
                toast.show();
                controller.deleteSchedule(getId);
                onResume();
            }
        });
        ArrayList schedule = new ArrayList();
        schedule.clear();
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM schedules";
        Cursor c1 = controller.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null & c1.getCount() != 0) { //if there is item in the cursor
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {  //start to move to position
                do {
                    getSchedule schedule1 = new getSchedule();  //create object of the class getParticipant
                    schedule1.setscheduleId(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleId")));  //set the friend id in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleName(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleName")));  //set the friend name in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleDuration(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("scheduleDuration")));
                    schedule.add(schedule1);  //add the object to arraylist
                } while (c1.moveToNext());  //if still have item in the cursor, loop again
            }
        }
        c1.close();
        listadapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), schedule);//create object of adapter class by
        //passing a context and arraylist
        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(listadapter);  //set the adapter

    }
}

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable updateRunnable= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {  listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     }
        });
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {   //when user resume from an intent
    super.onResume();
    handler.post(updateRunnable);
    if (getListView() != null) {   //if the list view is not null
        updateData();     //call the method updateData() to update the listView
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public void updateData(){
    final DBController controller = new DBController(getActivity());
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> scheduleList = controller.getAllSchedules();
    if (scheduleList.size()!=0){
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                scheduleId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleId);
                String getId = scheduleId.toString();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getId, duration);
                toast.show();
                controller.deleteSchedule(getId);
                onResume();
            }
        });
        ArrayList schedule = new ArrayList();
        schedule.clear();
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM schedules";
        Cursor c1 = controller.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null & c1.getCount() != 0) { //if there is item in the cursor
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {  //start to move to position
                do {
                    getSchedule schedule1 = new getSchedule();  //create object of the class getParticipant
                    schedule1.setscheduleId(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleId")));  //set the friend id in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleName(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("scheduleName")));  //set the friend name in the object
                    schedule1.setscheduleDuration(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("scheduleDuration")));
                    schedule.add(schedule1);  //add the object to arraylist
                } while (c1.moveToNext());  //if still have item in the cursor, loop again
            }
        }
        c1.close();
        ListAdapter listadapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), schedule);//create object of adapter class by
        //passing a context and arraylist
        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(listadapter);  //set the adapter
    }
}
}
```

This is my adapter class.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long countdown;
private TextView scheduleDuration;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
ArrayList<getSchedule> objects;

ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<getSchedule> scheduleList) {
    ctx = context;  //set the context
    objects = scheduleList; //set the arraylist
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx  //set the layout
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    getSchedule schedule = objects.get(position);
    final DBController controller = new DBController(ctx);
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {  //if view is null
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_schedule_entry, parent, false);
    }
    final TextView scheduleId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleId);
    scheduleId.setText(schedule.getscheduleId());
    TextView scheduleName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleName);
    scheduleName.setText(schedule.getscheduleName());
    scheduleDuration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleDuration);
    int convert = Integer.parseInt(schedule.getscheduleDuration());
    countdown = 60 * convert * 1000;
    startTimer();
    return view;
}

private void startTimer() {

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdown, 500) {
        // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
        // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

            scheduleDuration.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600,
                    (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60)));
            // format the textview to show the easily readable format

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
            scheduleDuration.setText("Time up!");
        }

    }.start();
}
}
```

this is my getSchedule class:

```
public class getSchedule {
String scheduleId;
String scheduleName;
String scheduleDuration;

public String getscheduleId(){
    return scheduleId;
}

public void setscheduleId(String id){
    this.scheduleId=id;
}

public String getscheduleName(){
    return scheduleName;
}

public void setscheduleName(String name){
    this.scheduleName=name;
}

public String getscheduleDuration(){
    return scheduleDuration;
}

public void setscheduleDuration(String duration){
    this.scheduleDuration = duration;
}
}
```

i am trying to retrieve the duration (in minutes) of every items in my database and create a countdown timer for every items in a listview. But the timer just stucked there...Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use updated Adapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private long countdown;
    private TextView scheduleDuration;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    ArrayList<getSchedule> objects;
    private String Duration = "";
    boolean flag = true;
    ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<getSchedule> scheduleList) {
        ctx = context;  //set the context
        objects = scheduleList; //set the arraylist
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx  //set the layout
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        getSchedule schedule = objects.get(position);
        final DBController controller = new DBController(ctx);
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {  //if view is null
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_schedule_entry, parent, false);
        }
        final TextView scheduleId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleId);
        scheduleId.setText(schedule.getscheduleId());
        TextView scheduleName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleName);
        scheduleName.setText(schedule.getscheduleName());
        scheduleDuration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scheduleDuration);
        scheduleDuration.setText(Duration);
        int convert = Integer.parseInt(schedule.getscheduleDuration());
        countdown = 60 * convert * 1000;
        if(flag){
            startTimer();
            flag = false;
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void startTimer() {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdown, 500) {
            // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
            // milliseconds

            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

                Duration =String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600,
                        (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60));
                // format the textview to show the easily readable format
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                Duration = "Time up!";
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. The timer is now moving, but it was totally messed up. It was like entering a multiple loops. For example, it starts from 59, then 58, then 59,58,57,58,57,56,59,58,59 something like that...

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a timer each time a view is loaded. Which means that if you scroll up and down a few times in your listview you could end up with hundreds of times running in the background. VERY BAD. also you're not using a ViewHolder. You should use one, it will boost performance greatly.Other than that the correct way to do this seems to me that it is the following. (I recently did exactly the same thing)

your getSchedule object should have a function that calculates how much time is left for that countdown:

```
public function String getTimeLeft(){
   String timeLeft;
   .
   .
   return timeLeft; 
}
```

and in the getView method in the adapter do something like:

```
  timeLeftTextView.setText(getSchedule.getTimeLeft());
```

and in your activity

```
// class variables
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable updateRunnable= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     }
        });
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    handler.postRunnable(updateRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() { 
    super.onStop(); 
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);
}
```

and don't forget to call `handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your helps. However, it is still stucked. I have followed your instruction, i have already included a function of getscheduleDuration() in my getSchedule class. I have converted the duration into a string and stored inside getSchedule class, and then convert it back to integer in my ListAdapter class. I have already updated my question. Can you check if anything i did wrong?

Comment: You didn't do what I said. You are still starting a timer at each getView call.  I offered you an alternative....The handler approach INSTEAD of the timers. not both of them at the same time. If you follow my approach your all your listview elements will be updated using ONLY ONE handler while with your approach you create hundreds of timers ! Apart from that you are not implementing the timers approach correctly.  The views in ListView are recycled..You can't reference them in background threads or you ll end up with weird behaviours like you allready are.

Comment: this results in a 'blinking' listview depending on what you have in it. (i.e. data will keep getting reloaded from the objects)